# How to combine elements in Karatsuba multiplication

Tags: c, algorithm, multiplication, karatsuba

I'm trying to implement multiplication using the Karatsuba algorithm.
The usual bit masking and shifting approach implemented in `mul_kar2()` works.

In `mul_kar2_au()`, I'm struggling with combining the individual components into a "single number" using a union, but can be an array. When I combine them, like in math school, and cast on 64-bit integer - it works (line commented with `//`). When I 'put them together' it doesn't. I know I have to emulate mathematical operation, but don't know how.
I don't want to use 64-bit integer as if it was on 32-bit processor/microcontroller, and also I want to extend it into 128-bit multiplication which is not present in arm64, not in hardware, so I have nowhere to cast it on.

```
typedef union
{
    uint32_t au32[2];
    uint16_t au16[4];
} au64_u;

au64_u mul_kar2_au(au64_u aru64)
{
    uint32_t ha, hb, la, lb, z2, z1, z0;
    int m = sizeof(uint32_t)*CHAR_BIT, m_2 = m/2;
    au64_u res;
    uint32_t a = aru64.au32[1];
    uint32_t b = aru64.au32[0];

    ha = a >> m_2;
    hb = b >> m_2;
    la = (uint16_t)a;
    lb = (uint16_t)b;
    z2 = ha * hb;
    z0 = la * lb;
    z1 = (ha + la) * (hb + lb) - z2 - z0;

    //uint64_t res = ((uint64_t)z2 << (m2 * 2)) + ((uint64_t)z1 << m2) + (uint64_t)z0;
    aru64.au16[0] = z0;
    aru64.au16[1] = (uint16_t)z1;
    aru64.au16[2] = z1 >> m_2;
    aru64.au16[3] = z2;

    return aru64;
}
```

And this is a result:

```
m=32, m_2=16
a=1458354473 (0x56ecb929)
b=1458354473 (0x56ecb929)

y=a*b:
2126797768919107729     0x1d83e74d75844891

t=mul_kar2(a, b):
2126797768919107729     0x1d83e74d75844891

t=mul_kar2_au(a, b):
7606718021055826065     0x69907dbcef984891
```

As can be seen only the last (least significant) 16 bits are correct.

The whole program can be found [here](https://dpaste.com/BCBRQNKQC).

If it's math question I will put it in correct department.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256882/discussion-on-question-by-tansy-how-to-combine-elements-in-karatsuba-multiplicat); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

*In math school*, you *add* properly aligned parts.
Using A,a and B,b for single character factor part designators:
z0: `abab abab`
z1: `(A+a)(B+b)`
z2: `ABAB ABAB`
summing:
`ABAB ABAB abab abab`
`+   (A+a)(B+b)`

```
aru64.au16[1] = (uint16_t)z1;
aru64.au16[2] = z1 >> m_2;
```

ignores the upper half of z0 and the lower one of z2.
For one way to avoid problems with the size of `z1` see the bottom of en.wikipedia's paragraph on [the Implementation of Karatsuba's multiplication algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Implementation).

Comment: If you read the code, you notice commented line (//res = ((uint64_t)z2 << (m2 * 2)) + ((uint64_t)z1 << m2) + (uint64_t)z0;) which is exactly the same as Wikipedia implementation you suggest. And that's not an answer, vascular it requires word as wide as the result, which is exactly what I can't use and want to solve.

Comment: My post answers your one explicit question: *How to combine elements in Karatsuba multiplication* (?) by pointing out you *drop* part of sub-products instead of adding them. It refers you to one presentation of one viable way to avoid number size problems beyond the common problem of handling carry in a "high level" programming language. Of all the attempts to apply Karatsuba's to just a couple of words in a C-like language, I think [this one](/q/41718565) to have useful answers.

Comment: So what you purpose is to do multiplication of (a + b) · (c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd.

Comment: I advise, suggest, even *propose* to do this as the about shortest "long" multiplication, yes. [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/manual/Karatsuba-Multiplication): *MUL_TOOM22_THRESHOLD can be as little as 10 limbs*. Even for 128 bits using 32×32 multiplication, they wouldn't try Karatsuba's (=Toom-Cook 2(or 22)).

Answer (score 1):

Answering a different question, actually:
*How to get the full product of a 32×32 multiplication using 32-bit arithmetic exclusively?*
Caveat: tried, but not seriously tested

```
/** full 64 bit product from multiplying two uint32_t factors
 *  using 32-bit arithmetic exclusively, assuming little endian storage order */
static const int HALF_BIT = 16;  // or 2 * CHAR_BIT - whatever
typedef union {
    uint32_t au32[2];
    uint16_t au16[4];
} au64_u;

/** return the product of the factors in aru64.au32 assuming little endian order */
au64_u product(au64_u aru64)
{
    au64_u result;
    uint32_t  // good thing multiplication is commutative
        a  = aru64.au32[1], b  = aru64.au32[0],
        la = (uint16_t)a,   lb = (uint16_t)b,
        ha = aru64.au16[3], hb = aru64.au16[1],
        low = la * lb, high = ha * hb,
        mid1 = ha * lb, mid = la * hb;
//  result.au32[0] = low + (mid1+mid << HALF_BIT);  // for expensive multiplication
    result.au32[0] = a * b;  // this includes the lower halves of ha*lb & la*hb
    // two k bit numbers can be added into a "k*k" product without a 2k carry
    mid1 += low >> HALF_BIT;
    // this addition needs to include all the low order bits
    //  to get the carry into the upper half right - and may produce a carry out
    mid += mid1;
    if (mid < mid1)
        high += 1<<HALF_BIT;
    result.au32[1] = high + (mid >> HALF_BIT);

    return result;
}
```

— no recursion, no Toom‐Cook.
For a not so different way to handle carries see [Ben Voigt's answer](/a/29722382) on how to get the upper half of a 64×64 bit product.

Comment: For a quadruple width product, carry handling gets to be a major nuisance.

Comment: I had [tested it](https://dpaste.com/7BVBHP47V) and it seems to work. Now I try to understand what it does. Thought it's not a formal answer to my question I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication of a two 32-bit integers into 64-bit product,  using long multiplication of 4 16-bit 'digits'.

```
typedef union
    {
    u32 au32[2];
    u16 au16[4];
    } au64_u;

au64_u mul_2x32_long(au64_u aru64)
{
    au64_u result;
    uint32_t \
        la = aru64.au16[0], ha = aru64.au16[1],
        lb = aru64.au16[2], hb = aru64.au16[3];
    // high << 32  + mid << 16             + low << 0;
    // ha*hb << 32 + (ha*bl + la*hb) << 16 + la*lb << 0;
    uint32_t \
    word_bits = sizeof(uint32_t)*CHAR_BIT/2,
    hcarry = 0, lcarry = 0,
    high = ha*hb,
    mid = ha*lb + la*hb,
    low = la*lb,
    hhalf, lhalf;

    if (mid < ha*lb)
        hcarry = 1;
    lhalf = low + (mid << word_bits);
    if (lhalf<low)
        lcarry = 1;
    hhalf = high + (mid >> word_bits) + (hcarry << word_bits) + lcarry;
    result.au32[0] = lhalf;
    result.au32[1] = hhalf;

    return result;
}
```

It solves the problem of multiplication, though it's not Karatsuba algorithm.

It's slightly slower (~6%) than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77992826) and longer ([28 lines](https://dpaste.com/HZ4FW4862) vs [25 lines](https://dpaste.com/FWX9AR8GT)) but uses 4 multiplications. Just like in definition of long multiplication.

Comment: I know but it's clearer and easier to read.